# How do populate a new column with data based on time range in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, datetime

```
Time_duration = df['period']
print (Time_duration)

0        23:59:56
1        23:59:56
2        23:59:55
3        23:59:53
4        23:59:52
           ...
74187    00:00:18
74188    00:00:09
74189    00:00:08
74190    00:00:03
74191    00:00:02
```

How can I then add a new column to this where I can specify each cell to be grouped hourly. for instance, all the transactions within 00:00:00 to 00:59:59 to be filled with 1, transactions within 01:00:00 to 01:59:59 to be filled with 2, and so on till 23:00:00 to 23:59:59 to be filled with 24.

```
0        23:59:56        24
1        23:59:56        24
2        23:59:55        24
3        23:59:53        24
4        23:59:52        24
           ...
74187    00:00:18         1
74188    00:00:09         1
74189    00:00:08         1
74190    00:00:03         1
74191    00:00:02         1
```

Comment: What is `df['period'].dtype`?

Comment: object data type

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime as dt

def hr_rt(t_str=str):
    time = dt.datetime.strptime(t_str, "%H:%M:%S")
    return time.hour + 1
df3['hr'] = df3.time.apply(hr_rt)


 sr_no      time  hr
0      0  23:59:56  24
1      1  23:59:56  24
2      2  23:59:55  24
3      3  23:59:53  24
4      4  23:59:52  24
```

> I guess this should help

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the column is a `Timedelta` then use integer division by one hour.

```
#df['period'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['period'])

df['hour'] = (df['period'] // pd.Timedelta(hours=1)) + 1
```

---

```
    period  hour
0 23:59:56    24
1 23:59:56    24
2 23:59:55    24
3 23:59:53    24
4 23:59:52    24
5 00:00:18     1
6 00:00:09     1
7 00:00:08     1
8 00:00:03     1
9 00:00:02     1
```